# PHP Function ideas for Online Registration system

Tags: php, jquery, sql, arrays, time

Any idea of what would be the best way of writing a function in PHP for an online registration system with possibility of objects' occupancy;

***Just to be clear:***
I want to check the availability of one object in the database by writing a function and by comparing two variables:

1. Starting time of reservations;
2. Their duration (finishing time);

So when a new reservation is entered I check the database; if it doesn't pass the limit of objects in that period (by comparing to previous reservations) it gives a message which I will then pass it to JavaScript and enable the Submission button; but if it passes the limit in my JavaScript I'll suggest a duration which is available for the entered Starting Time;

In my current PHP function I am having some problems:

- First I am using so many variables and so many loops (which may cause the system slow if it gets bigger) and the code seems quite messy!
- It doesn't recognize the difference between serial or concurrent reservations therefore it behaves the same to these reservations.

Here is a snippet of my function:

```
$reservation = new Reservation;
$reservations = $reservation -> fetch_all();
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
for ($j = $res_code['res_code_st']; $j < $res_code['res_code_fi']; $j++) {
    for ($i = $reservation['res_code_st']; $i < $reservation['res_code_fi']; $i++) {
    if ($i == $j) {
        $count = $count + 1;
            $arr[] = $reservation['res_code_st'];
                        $arr[] = $reservation['res_code_fi'];
                        break 2;
```

Which actually I'm storing time in this format;
For example for 12:30 I'm storing 1230 or for 09:20 I'm storing 0920 and then I'm checking every minute of any item with every minute of new reservation (everything happens in the same day: Days don't matter!) and in case it finds a match I count it as a new reservation in that period (the reason why it doesn't differ concurrency and serial);

I believe it should be simple but I'm kinda confused and my mind doesn't work for a better solution right now!

Thanks for your times :)

**EDIT**

I tried the suggested way of @kamil-maraz , I think it saves some time for reducing complexity but I still couldn't figure out how to check the concurrency.
Let me give one example:

There are four possibility of disturbance I try to show in this symbolic figure,

Suppose each line is a reservation across time, first line is for new reservation and next four are already stored in the DB;

Four disturbance are as :

- One that starts before and ends at the middle of new request,
- One that starts before and ends after the new request;
- One that is completely inside the new reservation;
- One that starts after the new request and ends after it;

  ```
            0-----------------0    
     0--------------------------------0
      0--------------0    
                       0----------0
                 0-----0

  $result = $db -> prepare('SELECT Count(reservation_id) FROM reservations WHERE (res_code_st < ? AND res_code_fi > ?) OR (res_code_st > ? AND res_code_fi < ?) OR (res_code_st < ? AND res_code_fi > ?) OR (res_code_st < ? AND res_code_fi > ?)');
  $result -> execute(array($res_code['res_code_st'], $res_code['res_code_st'], $res_code['res_code_st'], $res_code['res_code_fi'], $res_code['res_code_st'], $res_code['res_code_fi'], $res_code['res_code_fi'], $res_code['res_code_fi']));
  $row = $result -> fetch();
  ```

This is giving me the number of reservations in the interval of new request; But what about this case:

```
0--------------------------0
 0-----0
          0-----0
                   0------0
```

Although in the interval there are 4 reservations which is invalid (Suppose the #object limit == 3 ), but since at each time not more than 2 reservations are made it is still valid (the concurrency problem which I was talking about).

Any idea how should I change the SQL function to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that it could be done entirely on the database. You are fetching all results and then you do some magic over data. But you can do it through a database query.

for example somethging like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM reservations WHERE date < ... AND date > ... AND ... etc
```

then, in the php, you can test `count` ...

if you want to test different types of reservations, concurent, etc. you can use aggregated table ([Like somebedy used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674849/aggregate-data-tables) and you can store in rows types of reservations too.